# How do I apply multiple columns in window PartitionBy in Spark scala

Tags: apache-spark

```scala
val partitionsColumns = "idnum,monthnum"
val partitionsColumnsList = partitionsColumns.split(",").toList
val loc = "/data/omega/published/invoice"
val df = sqlContext.read.parquet(loc)
val windowFunction = Window.partitionBy  (partitionsColumnsList:_*).orderBy(df("effective_date").desc)
```

> ```
> <console>:38: error: overloaded method value partitionBy with alternatives:
> (cols: org.apache.spark.sql.Column*)     org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec <and>
> (colName: String,colNames: String*)org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec
> cannot be applied to (String)
> val windowFunction = Window.partitionBy(partitionsColumnsList:_*).orderBy(df("effective_date").desc)
> ```

Is it possible to send List of Columns to `partitionBy` method Spark/Scala?

I have implemented for passing one column to `partitionBy` method which worked. I don't know how to pass multiple columns to `partitionBy` Method

basically I want to pass `List(Columns)` to `partitionBy` method

Spark version is 1.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Window.partitionBy`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html#partitionBy-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) has the following definitions:

> ```
> static WindowSpec partitionBy(Column... cols)
> ```
>
> Creates a WindowSpec with the partitioning defined.
>
> ```
> static WindowSpec partitionBy(scala.collection.Seq<Column> cols)
> ```
>
> Creates a WindowSpec with the partitioning defined.
>
> ```
> static WindowSpec partitionBy(String colName, scala.collection.Seq<String> colNames)
> ```
>
> Creates a WindowSpec with the partitioning defined.
>
> ```
> static WindowSpec partitionBy(String colName, String... colNames)
> ```
>
> Creates a WindowSpec with the partitioning defined.

With your example,

```
val partitionsColumnsList = partitionsColumns.split(",").toList
```

You can use it like:

```
Window.partitionBy(partitionsColumnsList.map(col(_)):_*).orderBy(df("effective_date").desc)
```

Or

```
Window.partitionBy(partitionsColumnsList.head, partitionsColumnsList.tail _* ).orderBy(df("effective_date").desc)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also apply multiple columns for partitionBy by assigning the column names as a list to the variable and use that in the partitionBy argument as below:

```
val partitioncolumns = List("idnum","monthnum")
val w = Window.partitionBy(partitioncolumns:_*).orderBy(df("effective_date").desc)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me:

```
Window.partitionBy(partitionsColumnsList.map(col(_)):_*).orderBy(df("effective_date").desc)
```